# What is the difference between Cassy's snapshots and consistent backups? Cassy is a backup tool for Cassandra

Tags: cassy

i want to know the characteristics of Cassy backup and how to use them in actual operation. Specifically, from an operational design perspective, what is the difference between snapshots and consistent backups, what types of usage patterns can you use each or in combination, and what are the benefits and tradeoffs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are snapshot. Consistent snapshot (a.k.a cluster-wide snapshot/backup) is a special snapshot that is transactionally consistent.
Imagine a transaction T in a payment application.
T: sends $100 from an account A to an account B.
T actually has 2 processes like deducting $100 from A's account and adding $100 to B's account.

If you take a normal snapshot, the transaction is not cared so a produced snapshot might not have the result of one of the processes.
Instead, transactionally consistent snapshot is either a snapshot before or after the transaction occurs.

Transactionally consistent backup is useful only when quorum of C* disks are broken and the data is lost.
Otherwise, normal snapshot is enough since C* cluster still has quorum of data alive and the latest data can just be synchronized.

Snapshot should be taken regularly like once in a week or 2 weeks.
Cluster-wide snapshot can be taken in a longer time span just for the worst case scenario.